# Why does installation of Unity Tweak Tool fail with Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: software-installation, 19.10, unity-tweak-tool

Why does [Installing Unity Tweak Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bej11.jpg) fail with Ubuntu 19.10?

[image: Installing Unity Tweak]

I already did these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install notify-osd   
sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar
```

Comment: Please describe in detail how did you get to this point? Which commands did you use before you got this error? Please avoid posting photos of the screen. Post screenshots using the built-in app and shortcuts instead. For text based output, such as contents of the terminal window, please copy and paste into the edit question window and format the output as code using the { } icon above the edit window.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to install Unity Tweak Tool in the first place? Ubuntu 19.10 doesn't come with Unity by default.

Answer (score 5):

You are not using Unity, so don't install Unity Tweak Tool as it's for the Unity desktop.

From the screenshot I can see that you're using the GNOME desktop. In this case if you want to tweak some desktop settings you'll want to install GNOME Tweaks:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```